# AndroidX refactoring: Old support libraries are still used in other third-parth libraries

Tags: android, androidx

I'm trying refactor from `Android Support Library` to `AndroidX`, so I removed `com.android.support:xxx` dependencies and used `androidx.xxx` instead. But some other libraries I used in my project are still depending `Android Support Library`. If I remove the support library, they maybe can't find classes. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use.  What should I do to ensure that I don't use "Android Support Library" and "AndroidX" at the same time? Thanks in advance.